# Веб-фриланс

Tags: cms

Здравствуйте. Задумали с парочкой одногруппников подрабатывать на фрилансе разработкой сайтов. Некоторый опыт имеется. Да вот беда: ни одного проекта взять не можем. За особо сложный пока браться не решаемся. Пишем все "ручками". Но требуют или сразу на CMS или сразу находятся люди типа "сделаю на Joomla за 2 дня за $50". И ясен пень, что мы со своими  "2 недели за 300-500$" никому не нужны. А ни с одной CMS никогда не работали. Вот посоветуйте какие стОит изучить и собственно как? Приходилось только языки да фреймворки изучать. Там синтаксис и вперед! А тут модули и пр. Какие и главное как изучить и научиться делать сайты быстро и недорого, чтоб с ними конкурировать? И важным фактором было бы простое "допиливание", т.е. дописывание при необходимости.

Comment: Потолкайтесь среди знакомых, может кому-то что-то нужно.

И строго говоря, для состояния - без какого-либо опыта (заметьте - я ничего не говорю про знания, только об практическом опыту) - 300 у.е. - немыслимо много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Въехать» в Joomla мне лично помогла книга, где пошагово писали компонент, [одна из этих](http://www.packtpub.com/Joomla), и затем большой неспешный заказ, который развивался в течение года, на основе моего компонента.

Не связываясь с CMS, можете браться писать приложения для Facebook / ВК — это ближе к вашей специализации, мне кажется. Напишите по одному пробному, и вперёд.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос - отчаяние. Отчаяние присуще молодым. Молодость - это возраст, когда кажется, что "все могу, но не ценят". И тогда наступает отчаяние. Временное. Те, кто найдет в себе силу понять, что он далеко еще не является тем, кем станет лет через 5-10, станут профессионалами с $$. Так что не отчаивайтесь и продолжайте работать - успех не застанет себя ждать. Поверьте.

Answer (score 0):

Определить какую CMS учить очень просто, достаточно посмотреть по заказам на free-lance.ru. Это на текущий момент Joomla, Wordpress, ModX, остальное лень перечислять.

Но я думаю вы неверно ставите задачу. Берите мелкие проекты, всякие там калькуляторы, парсеры, исправления, дополнения. Я к примеру без всяких этих CMS обхожусь и ничего, заказов хватает.

Comment: @fStrange, ну впринципе определить-то да. Думаю с Joomla начнем. Только вот как ее изучать. Где бы русскоязычный справочник/инструкцию/документацию найти. Даже не знаю с какой стороны к ней подойти)
А проекты... Просто хочется взять целый сайт на недели 2 и делать. А не исправлять чужое - не люблю я такого)

Comment: Да лан. "Определить какую CMS учить очень просто, достаточно посмотреть по заказам на free-lance.ru..." 100500 заказов на сайт на Джумле еще не повод связываться с Джумлой. Уж тогда смотреть на соотношение числа заказов и стоимости. Вполне допускаю, что более редкие CMS (тат же ModX) может быть интереснее по условиям. Ну а еще можно и третий критерий добавить: нормальность сообщества CMS. Тут Джумла проигрывает по всем фронтам: чуть столкнешься с проблемой посерьезнее - фиг найдешь, где и у кого спросить совета.

Answer (score 0):

Одногруппники, ни беритесь сразу за `Joomla`, лучше всего тогда начать с `wordpress`. Как учить? Да легко, ставите себе его, пилите как хотите, меняете дизайны, добавляется всякие плагины, в общем учитесь с ним работать, за одно и поймете что да как в CMS, а потом уже можно и в код будет залезть, напр. свой плагин написать (часто приходится чужие допиливать). Я вот сколько работаю, с `джумла` мне мелочи попадались.

Answer (score 0):

Так а что неправильного?
У Вас нет опыта и практики, а вы уже хотите 300-500 долларов.
Для начала маленькие заказы по 10 долларов берите и пилите, да и можно не командой а каждый сам по себе, вот когда у вас появится опыт и практика, а так же портфолио, вот тогда можете собираться в команду и браться за более крупные проекты по 300-500 долларов.
а когда станете командой будет еще больше .

Comment: @savro, проблем сделать не будет. 300-500$ на четверых - имхо мы много не требуем.

Comment: Вы поймите клиенту, глубоко наплевать четверо вас или 10 или вы одиночка, пока вы не набьёте себе репутацию и портфолио, ни кто не даст вам проект на 300-500 долларов.

Делайте мелкие проекты,правки, элементарные вещи, получайте отзывы репутацию,портфолио, в первых 2-3 месяца о заработке говорить не стоит.
Конкуренция как вы сами видите бешеная, в вебе народу очень много, и бюджеты там редко большие. И на большие бюджеты нужена хорошая репутация как минимум.